# How to use question mark with URL in htacess

Tags: .htaccess, url, short-url

I'm using this code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z].+)\.html$ view.php?question=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

It is showing like this `what-is-your-name.html`
but I want to use like this:

```
what-is-your-name?.html
```

How can I use this?

Comment: You can't. `?` will mark new parameter in url and there will be variable in GET `.html`.

Answer (score 0):

with

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z].+).html$ view.php?question=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

with

> what-is-your-name.html

you will receive as `$1 what-is-you-name`

if you change the RewriteRule to

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z].+)$ view.php?question=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

with

> what-is-your-name?.html

you will receive the same as `$1` (again `what-is-you-name`, without the "?")

so, as you put the flag [QSA], you will receive

```
view.php?question=what-is-your-name&.html
```

If you don't want to do it so, and you want to receive the questionmark in your PHP, you should urlencode() it.

Then your link should be:

what-is-your-name%3F.html

and with your first RewriteRule, your php will receive:
$_GET['question'] --> "what-is-your-name?"

Comment: i have this data in row example what is your name? but  i am using this code RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z].+)$ view.php?question=$1 [L,QSA,NC] and it is not allow ? question mark so i want to allow question mark if question mark is there then it will show if not there then it will open normally example i am Ali in this row no question mark there so it will show normally

Comment: Question mark is not part of the path from the URL: it's an special character reserved to separate the path and the parameters. If you want to pass it so your PHP file receives it, you should urlencode() it.